# MySQL - Adding a JOIN to existing query

Tags: mysql, sql

Having troubles adding a LEFT JOIN & INNER JOIN, combined, to an existing query.

I have two main tables; "photoSearch" containing all searchable data for my photos, and "photos", containing all data for my photos. I am using FULLTEXT across 3 fields in "photoSearch" to get relevant photoID's and then grabs the data from the "photos" table, like copyrights, sizes, dimensions...

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT p.photoID, p.setID, p.headline, p.caption, p.height, p.width, p.size, p.copyright
FROM photos AS p,
      (SELECT photoID FROM photoSearch WHERE MATCH (allPeople, allKeywords, shortCaption)
      AGAINST ('+byline' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0,50) AS photoIDs
WHERE p.photoID = photoIDs.photoID;
```

I now need to modify this query to include a LEFT JOIN and an INNER JOIN which gets any names of people shown in each photo, to print on-screen. Some photos do not have any people, hence needing a LEFT JOIN. I have this data across two tables (normalized); "photoPeople" and "people", so I came up with this join:

**My Join** (which needs adding to the above query)

```
LEFT JOIN ( photoPeople AS pp INNER JOIN people AS pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.PeopleID)
ON p.photoID = pp.photoID
```

But I'm finding it hard to fit it in my original query, as the sub-select query is in the comma delimited FROM list - it's confusing me. I also want to make sure that I'm not affecting the performance of the FULLTEXT index by joining where I shouldn't.

I did try adding it straight after the sub-select (before WHERE) but I was getting SQL errors saying it did not recognise column p.photoID.

Both original query and the DB design is not mine.

Any help or guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.photoID, 
    p.setID, 
    p.headline, 
    p.caption, 
    p.height, 
    p.width, 
    p.size, 
    p.copyright,
    pe.*
FROM 
    photos p
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT photoID 
        FROM photoSearch 
        WHERE MATCH (allPeople, allKeywords, shortCaption) AGAINST ('+byline' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        LIMIT 50
    ) pids ON p.photoID = pids.photoID
LEFT JOIN
    photoPeople pp ON p.photoID = pp.photoID
LEFT JOIN
    people pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID
```

I don't see a need to `INNER JOIN` the `people` table on the `LEFT JOIN` because if the `LEFT JOIN` is `NULL`, the `people` will also be `NULL`

Comment: Hey, thanks buddy. It does throw a tiny error; "Every derived table must have its own alias". Any ideas where the alias needs to go?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid, I corrected that mistake right after I posted, try the query now.

Comment: I just tried the updated version and still throws the same error. I can't work that out, I thought the derived table had an alias of "pids"?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid, oops! I didn't see the `LIMIT 50` all the way to the right. Now it should *hopefully* work. =D

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT pp.photoID,name FROM photoPeople AS pp INNER JOIN people AS pe 
    ON pp.peopleID = pe.PeopleID) aa
ON p.photoID = aa.photoID
```